# Spring boot mvc with Thymeleaf4. Nested fragments

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Have a spring boot mvc project, on which I try to learn the Thymeleaf4(I know there is a never version, but currently sticking to the one, I've started from) engine functionality.

Struck to a point of the tutorial, which shows that I can define fragment 1,2,3 where fragment 3 will take in some values. From this point it is said to be possible to provide other fragments to the one, which takes arguments.

Here is what I have defined in a file fragments/menu.html:

```
<div th:fragment="a">MENU</div>
<div th:fragment="withArgs(arg1,arg2)">
    <p th:text="'You have provided: ' + ${arg1} + ' and ' + ${arg2}">ERROR</p>
</div>
<div th:fragment="third">YUS</div>
```

From which I want to call 'withText' with 'a' and 'third':

```
<div th:replace="fragments/menu :: withArgs(fragments/menu :: a, fragments/menu :: third)"></div>
```

The example states to use '~{fragments/menu :: a}', but says to be optional, and even with these I get:

```
Could not parse as fragment selection: "fragments/menu :: withArgs(fragments/menu :: a, fragments/menu :: third)"
```

Can't understand how to properly do this.